# close firefox tabs with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript code which opens a new tab in browser from a list each 50seconds, but the browser will crash after 50tabs or more.
so I want to close new tab and open another one each 50 seconds.

my code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function openWindow(){
    window.open('"about:blank"');
    var x = document.getElementById('a').value.split('\n');
    atTime = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (x[i].indexOf('.') > 0) {
        site = x[i];
        if (x[i].indexOf('://') < 0) { site = 'http://' + x[i]; }
        setTimeout("window.open('" + site + "')", atTime);
        atTime += 50000;
      }
    }
}
</script>
<style>
html, body
{
    height : 99%;
    width  : 99%;
}

textarea
{
    height : 80%;
    width  : 90%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="a"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Open Windows" onClick="openWindow()">
<input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="document.getElementById('a').value=''">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Somehow, I can't see your website being very popular...

Answer (score 0):

`window.open` returns a reference to the new window. Call `close` on that handle.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.close

note btw:

FAQ

How can I prevent the confirmation message asking the user whether he wants to close the window?
    You can not. New windows not opened by javascript can not as a rule be closed by JavaScript. The JavaScript Console in Mozilla-based browsers will report the warning message: "Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script." Otherwise the history of URLs visited during the browser session would be lost.

Answer (score 0):

window.close() should work to close tabs you opened (but it's not possible to close a tab you didn't open)

in fact it can't be closed unless it was opened by a script but there is a way to fool the browser into thinking that's the case:

```
window.open('','_parent','');
```

then you can use

```
window.close();
```

Putting it together:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function closeWindow() {
window.open('','_parent','');
window.close();
}
</script>
```

reference: http://www.yournewdesigner.com/css-experiments/javascript-window-close-firefox.html

Answer (score 0):

to close a firefox tab use 
    window.close()
this will close the current window.